# Making a table from JSON data in svg doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg

Below is my code, the table is not visible. I don't see it when the browser render it. But in chrome developer tool the elements are created.

HTML

```
    <svg id="ab" width="100%" height="100%"
          viewBox="-20 -20 800 800" 
          preserveAspectRatio="none"></svg>
```

JS

```
    function svgTable(data){
        var pair = d3.keys(data[0])

        d3.select("#ab")
          .append("foreignObject")
          .attr("width", 500)
          .attr("height", 500)
          .append("xhtml:table");

        d3.select("table")
          .append("tr")
          .attr("class", "head")
          .selectAll("th")
          .data(pair)
          .enter()
          .append("th")
          .html(function (d) {return d})

        d3.select("table")
          .selectAll("tr.data")
          .data(data).enter()
          .append("tr")
          .attr("class", "data")

        d3.selectAll("tr")
          .selectAll("td")
          .data(function(d) {return d3.entries(d)})
          .enter()
          .append("td")
          .html(function (d) {return d.value})
    }

    // var data = {"ABC":true,"XYZ":"False","Type":"all","ABC":true,"XYZ":"False","Type":"all"};

    d3.json("data.json", function(error,data){
        svgTable(data)
    })
```

What am I doing wrong ? I am using foreignObject  and also not using it in IE. I am latest google chrome.

Comment: Your last line is `)}`, but should be `})`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, I corrected it still its same. @peter

Comment: I get an error: `'#1' is not a valid selector`. Use a different id on the svg - it shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: What is in data.json?

Comment: data.json has json data which I mentioned in comment.

Comment: I changed id to #ab but still no change

Comment: Then `var pair = d3.keys(data[0])` should be `var pair = d3.keys(data)`. There is no 0 element in the data object.

Comment: Yes that did it thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var pair = d3.keys(data[0])` should be `var pair = d3.keys(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

var pair = d3.keys(data[0]) should be var pair = d3.keys(data). There is no 0 element in the data object. @peter

It worked